# Azure Search throws exception "Failed to execute query because it exceeded the maximum clause limit of 1024."

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm seeing this exception being thrown by search call to Azure Search:

"Message":"Failed to execute query because it exceeded the maximum clause limit of 1024.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperations.d__21`3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperationsExtensions.d__15.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown

I see that this is because of the search string being too long. But I'm not able to locate any documentation on this. I suppose this exception means that the unique number of terms in the searched string exceeds 1024. Is that correct?

We want to be able to anticipate this exception and handle it by cleaning up the search string in some way without losing valuable context in the search string. Should we limit the search string by some number of characters? Or by the number of unique terms in it? Any recommendations around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details on the Azure Search query size limits (and the scenario you are asking about specifically) here:
[Azure Search Query Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_querysizelimits)